How do I access my CSV file I downloaded on Mac, without encountering the error '[Errno 2] No such file or directory:'?
I am going through w3school's machine learning course and I am stuck on the Multiple Regression section. I downloaded their example CSV file and when I ran the following code:
import pandas
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")

X = df[['Weight', 'Volume']]
y = df['CO2']

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)

predictedCO2 = regr.predict([[2300, 1300]])

print(predictedCO2)

I got this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-a25fe74bc066> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from sklearn import linear_model
      3 
----> 4 df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
      5 
      6 X = df[['Weight', 'Volume']]

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    857         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    858             # Encoding
--> 859             handle = open(
    860                 handle,
    861                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'

So before looking anything up I checked the file to see if it was there and when I found it there I assumed that I should just make a copy, change the name, and use the new name for the file.
df = pandas.read_csv("co2.csv")

This did absolutely nothing to fix the problem. So, I looked into it and found that I needed the full path directory for file and copied the path that Mac has in the 'Where:' of the info page:
df = pandas.read_csv("/Users/drewolson/Documents/co2.csv")

Still nothing and I am utterly confused because everything I looked up said it would be solved by having the entire path directory and I swear I do. What am I missing?

What do you mean by "still nothing"? If you have provided the correct path to the file then you should see some change from the original problem.

maybe your path is different - maybe there are spaces or upper and lower chars. Maybe first use print( os.listdir("/full/path/to/folder") ) to check what Python sees in folder.

if file is accessible on web page without loging then you can use pandas.read_csv("http://example.com/path/to/data.csv")

You can pass both relative ("data.csv") and absolute filenames ("/Users/drewolson/Documents/co2.csv") to read_csv(). How do you exactly run your Python script? And what is your current working directory? You can see that with the command pwd.

@GuidoFlohr I am just using Google Colab. Though I do have PyCharm, I am using Colab because this is just practice, and it is more convenient to use Colab. It also says my current working directory is /content. I used to understand directories and all of that better, but I took a long break, so I have no idea what this means anymore.

Google Colab is a cloud service. It does not have access to your local hard disk, simply because JavaScript code running in your browser does not have access to your local hard disk. Well-known data sets like MNIST/Fashion MNIST are built into machine learning libraries but they are actually downloaded from the web, when you use them. You can somehow mount Google Drive into Colab but it's probably simpler to just install Python locally and run the code locally. You should also update your question and mention that you are talking about Google Colab.
